# Unexpected result due to order in Swift's pattern matching

Tags: pattern-matching, swift

Sorry for the "Shouldn't this work?" question. But I can't figure out a better way to phrase this.

```
enum MyEnum {
    case A, B, C
}

let tuple = (MyEnum.C, MyEnum.A)    
var x: String

switch tuple {
case (.A, _):
    x = "(A, something)"
case (_, .A):
    x = "(something, A)"
case (_, .B):
    x = "(something, B)"
case (.C, .C):
    x = "(C, C)"
default:
    x = "default"
}

x // -> "default"
```

`x` evaluates to `"default"`, which means the default branch was taken.

However, I was expecting `"(something, A)"` and the second case statement to match. From what I understood `(_, .A)` should match anything in the first tuple element, and `.A` in the second.

If I move the `(_, .A)` case to the top, it is matched as I expect it. Other tuples also match where I expect them to.

What am I missing? Why isn't this matched by the second case?

Comment: Interestingly reproducible...Also when I comment out any of the other case statements (other than `default`), it works as expected. Looks like a bug report is needed!

Comment: It seems like any other ordering of the test cases produces the correct result...going to check if its a playground thing or not..

Comment: It's not. I found it while writing a regular app. :) I'll definitely file a bug report unless someone here points out a mistake.

Comment: I don't see how it could be a feature...even switching the order of the 3rd and 4th case statements fixes it. Seems like a 1 in million chance you stumbled across this lol

Comment: Well, I'm just one of a million monkeys typing Swift right now. :)

Comment: A million monkeys? With any luck, soon we'll have Shakespeare in Swift. Or at least a few flappy bird clones.

Comment: Only the lucky monkeys get to type Swift, others like me are still on ObjC :[

Comment: Looks like a genyouwine bug!

Comment: It seems that the error is caused by the combination of the first two case statements at the beginning of the switch. If they are not at the beginning of the statement then there is no issue. It would be nice to look at the machine code produced, then again it will be scary.

Comment: Definitely a compiler bug, have you reported it?

Comment: Of course, I'll post here for any update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior has been corrected in beta 3. It now shows `(Something, A)` whatever the order is.